# osx - launchagent vs cronjob vs calendar alarm

Tags: finder, script

So I was wondering why would you choose one over the other on a mac if they essentially do the same thing?  Which is run a script on a specific time or frequency.  Does one of them actually wake up the sleeping mac and execute?

why would you use one over the other?

- launchagent
- cronjob
- calendar alarm

thanks

Comment: You could add third-party apps to your choices. I generally choose to use Keyboard Maestro as you create jobs (macros) with a GUI and it can run both graphical apps and scripts - and it does much more.

Answer (score 3):

## Prefer `launchd`

For non-graphical scripts, [`launchd`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/launchd/) is Apple's preferred approach.

`cron` is available but no longer recommended by Apple. This is for energy efficiency reasons as `cron` checks every minute for due tasks.

In comparison to `cron`, `launchd`'s time based trigger is limited but this allows `launchd` to reliably calculate an absolute date and time of future events. Knowing these dates, `launchd` can remain idle until they arrive.

Calendar.app's alarm is useful for graphical scripts, such as AppleScript and Automator. For this to work, your Mac must be logged in and awake.

### Graphical versus non-graphical scripts

**Graphical scripts** are those that interact with running Mac applications. These applications are assumed to have windows and a user interface. This means they require a graphical user session to work – and thus a user must be logged in for the application to be launched and kept running.

Graphical scripts include AppleScript and Automator.

**Non-graphical scripts** are those that limit their actions to command line tools and processes. They do not require a user to be logged in. The computer only needs to be awake for the script to complete its task.

Non-graphical scripts include shell scripts and command line tools.

### Waking or powering on for a script

None of the built-in tools will power on or wake your Mac to perform your script. You will need a third party tool, such as [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) for this. I am affiliated with Power Manager, so feel free to get in touch with any questions.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and tool reference. Greatly appreciated.  just last question... launchd remains idle until time of execution but cron checks every minute.  How is that possible since a process does have to check for time to assure they aren't any items to launch.  So wouldn't' both launchd and cron need to check repeatedly?  how does launchd know the right time to launch if it isn't checking on current time repeatedly?

Comment: Please can you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) regarding the specific differences between `launchd` and `cron`. This site works best when questions avoid discussions and are limited in scope.